# This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Tags: c++, windows, crash

Over the years, I've seen C++ applications the employ the "unusual way" language in a crash.  For example:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.  Please contact the application's support team for more information.

The first of these I debugged, it had something to do with a destructor being fired for a class, in an inheritance chain, that already had been deleted.  I can't remember the particulars better than that.  When I google this topic, I find one or two other suggested causes. For example, that the binaries themselves have become corrupt and must be re-written.

Overall, I find the information on this kind of crash to be much too thin.  I'd like to see two things:

1. A formal explanation of why this type of termination exists (and which Windows platforms, if relevant).
2. A list of all reasons, or at least the common reasons, why this type of crash occurs.

Anyone know where this information can be found?  Can anyone provide this information?

Comment: This is caused by rodents of unusual size:-)

Comment: ROUSs? I think it's more to do with flame bursts actually..

Comment: Rodents of unusual size? I don't think they exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This dialog is produced by the visual studio runtime, in response to `abort()`. `abort()` is by default called by e.g. `terminate()`. You'll get this from e.g. unhandled c++ exceptions, call to pure virtuals, failed assertions.

So, it's not platform dependent, but run-time library dependent. `abort()` is, by the c++ standard, required to terminate the program without executing destructors for automatic and static storage objects, and without calling `atexit()` handlers.